# How to add an error message in my_sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have reward point based website where user need to update reward point to shop on web portal. The code once he used is deleted from database. How could I can show an error message if a user is trying to use that code again that the code is already used.

```
enter code here

<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="";
    $db_name="bs1";
    $con=mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die("could not connect to mysql!!!");
    if($con=="")
    {
        echo "Database not connected!!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        $isdb=mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("database not available!!!!");
        if($isdb=="")
        {
            echo "database not selected!!!!";
        }
        else
        {   
            $emp_ID=$_POST['emp_ID'];
            $code=$_POST['code'];


            $query = mysql_query("select * from oc_sand_reward where `Code`='$code'") or die (mysql_error());
            $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $code_db=$data['Code'];
            $points_db=$data['Point'];
            if($code==$code_db)
            {
            $query1 = mysql_query("select * from oc_customer where `emp_ID`='$emp_ID'") or die (mysql_error());
            $data1=mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
            $customer_id=$data1['customer_id'];

            $query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `oc_customer_reward` (customer_id, emp_ID,  emp_name, order_id, description, Code, points, date_added) VALUES ($customer_id, $emp_ID,  '$emp_name', 0, 'rewarded', '$code', $points_db, NOW());");

            $query4=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `oc_customer_reward_history` (customer_id, emp_ID, description, Code, points) VALUES ($customer_id, $emp_ID, 'rewarded', '$code', $points_db)");

            $query3=mysql_query("DELETE FROM oc_sand_reward WHERE Code='$code'");



            header("location:http://localhost/bsl/index.php?route=account/account");
            exit();
            }
            else
            {

            }           
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated, you should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Add a boolean column to your `oc_sand_reward` table. If used set the value to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete it once used, you can do want Daan says or create another table with name maybe `used_points`.

Here after the reward point is used you structure a query to move the used point into table `used_points`.

Then whenever a user is trying to load a result point, you validate it against values in the `used_points` table

Comment: Yes I already use a table named oc_customer_reward where the used code is stored and deleted from the table oc_sand_reward so the user is not able to use the code once used. But the problem is that if a person is trying to use the used code again there is no any warning message is showing. So i want to display a message that "The code you are trying is already used" How could I display this message if a user is trying to use used code.

Comment: Then simply, generate a query to select all the unused codes in the oc_sand_reward table where the `field containing the unused codes`='the users input code'. Then you determine the number of rows returned. So if number of rows == 0 then echo or assign an error variable, THIS CODE HAS BEEN USED. I hope you are clear now

Comment: maybe  $user_input_code = $_POST['reward_point']                                                                                                          "SELECT reward_points FROM oc_sand_reward WHERE reward_points = '$user_input_code'".                                                                                                                        So if mysqli_num_rows($query) returns zero or false that means it has been used